# How to send reminders via Whatsapp through my Andriod app?

Tags: android, kotlin, whatsapp

I am starting an Android app project, which consists of a sort of planner. I want to send reminders of certain user-chosen activities via Whatsapp. I was told that Any.do has these, but I do not know how that can be done.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up a NESTJS server interfaced with TYPEORM and some form of SQL. That way, you can store the reminders you need, send them at regular intervals as needed, and delete them at expiration. What do you think?